# XPath: выбор узлов в порядке расположения

Tags: xpath, xml, xhtml, html

Здравствуйте.

XPath: как выбрать узлы разных типов в том же порядке, в котором они расположены на странице. Вопрос вот в чем:

```
//table//h2 | //table//td[@valign='top']
```

Я хочу таким образом получить список из заголовков и таблиц поочередно (заголовок1-таблица1-заголовок2-таблица2-...). Но у меня сначала идут все заголовки, потом все таблицы. Можно как-то изменить это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогли на rsdn.ru (спасибо avpavlov):

```
//table//*[local-name()='h2' or (local-name()='td' and @valign='top')]
```